# How to update NPM and solution-related frontend libraries/packages once we update the Node version?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm, eslint

**Brief introduction**

I am currently tasked with updating an outdated project`s NPM packages. As already mentioned, the solution is pretty outdated, so much so that specific versions of Node (^14.x.x) and NPM (^6.x.x) are required.

---

The following are the Objectives:

1. **Update Node to a stable version**, in this case we try to update to ^20.x.x since this seems to be the one which will be maintained the longest according to the following graph [**available here**](https://github.com/nodejs/Release)
   [image]
2. **Update NPM to latest supported version**, which at the time of writing this description is  10.2.5, *also this is supported by the Node version mentioned above*.
   [image: List item]

---

Once we have these Objectives, **the next steps** are to

- first update patch versions
- secondly update minor versions
- lastly read through major changes for each library and see what code could potentially be broken, if code has minimal to no chance to break for a specific library, the library shall be updated.

---

Here is the list of all the libraries that must be updated following the points mentioned above:

[image]

Once I have Updated both **Node** and **NPM** to the previously mentioned versions, I have followed **[this article](https://chrispennington.blog/blog/how-to-update-npm-packages-safely-with-npm-check-updates/)**, and I have managed to update both the patch as well as minor changes.

---

**The Problem**

Once all the patch and minor updates are ready, and I attempt to perform the `npm i` I am getting this constant error, whereby there seems to be some conflicts between the libraries seen in the image below:
[image]

and here is the continuation to it

[image]

Now, I have tried to to update with both **--force** and **--legacy-peer-deps**, however, additional issues are being shown, and from this point onwards, unfortunately, I can`t seem to see a solution to this.

I have tried to update each and one of the libraries shown in the images above, however, a similar issue was displayed.

My assumption is that this error messages might have something to do with the update of Node & NPM, however, this is just a bold assumption based on the observations

---

**My questions**, therefore, are pretty obvious:
What the actual issue could be?
What is the best way to solve this kind of issue?
Will these changes, if any solution available, potentially break the solution?

---

If anything is unclear, or you need additional information please do not hesitate to ask. Appreciate your time